# PHP $_POST array

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm building a webhook that will receive data from an external service.

In order to retrieve data, I'm using the following array:

```
$data = [
$_POST['aaa'],
$_POST['bbb'],
$_POST['ccc'],
$_POST['ddd'],
$_POST['eee']
];
```

Is it possible to build the same array without repeating $_POST? I mean something like:

```
$data = $_POST [
['aaa'],
['bbb'],
['ccc'],
['ddd'],
['eee']
];
```

Obviously, that code is wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = $_POST
```

This will build your new $data array the same way as your GLOBAL $_POST array including the POST Key names and their assigned values.

Also checkout extract($_POST), as this will extract each key to its same name variable, which may be easier to then reference in your web-hook or any functions or procedural code you uses from then on. This essentially does this:

```
$aaa = $POST['aaa']
$bbb = $POST['bbb']
$ccc = $POST['ccc']
```

etc etc
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: "$data = $_POST;" is exactly what I need (but I won't use "extract()" because of security reasons). Thanks! And thanks to Barmar and Christoff X, too: I've learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

There's no shortcut like that. You could use `array_map()`:

```
$data = array_map(function($key) {
    return $_POST[$key];
}, ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', ...]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for me would be:

1. For getting all the values in the $_POST array

`foreach($_POST as $value){
    $data[] = $value;
}`

2. For getting all the values and want to keep the key

`foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $data[$key] = $value;
}`

3. For getting a specific array of values from the array

`foreach(['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee'] as $column){
    $data[] = $_POST[$column];
}`

4. Just a good idea to always escape variables ;)

`$con = mysqli_connect('hostcleveranswer.com','USERyouearn','PWDanupv0Te','dropthemicDB')
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = mysqli_escape_string($con,$value);
}`

//i feel that was a good simple answer using tools without having to a learn a new function syntax